# Taking address of temporary

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to assign the return value of my function to a node, which is a pointer. I have tried it both with and without '&' but non of them seem to work. I am currently getting the error in the title. Without the '&'  get a "cannot convert node to *node in assignment" error

```
   class Node{

    public:
    int value;
    Node *left, *right;

    Node(int x, Node *l, Node *r){
        value = x;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};

class Tree{

public:
    Node *root;
    Tree(Node *r){
        root = r;
    }

    void add(int num){
       cout << "adding" << endl;
        root = add(root, num);//error occurs here
}

private:
    Node add(Node *parent, int num){

        cout << "im in..." << endl;

        if(parent == root && root == nullptr){
           cout << "root" << endl;
            Node n(num, nullptr, nullptr);
            return n;
        }

        if(parent == nullptr){
            Node next(num, nullptr, nullptr);
            cout << "actually adding" << endl;
            return next;

        }
        else if(num > parent->value){
           cout << "bigger" << endl;
            parent->right = add(parent->right, num);
        }
        else {
            cout << "smaller" << endl;
            parent->left = add(parent->left, num);
        }
    }
};

int main(){

    Node n1(100, nullptr,nullptr);

    Tree tree(&n1);
    tree.add(1);

        return 0;}
```

Comment: Using `std::shared_ptr` may help if you need to maintain multiple references to the same object.

Comment: You should post a minimal `main` that initializes a `Node` and enough of the `Node` class for people to be able to try this out

Comment: @asimes consider it done...

Comment: @mrnoobynoob how can you declare an object of that class within the class itself? Sorry, if it's possible cause I've never done so..

Comment: idk. im new to c++ and I know you can do that in Java...

Comment: The bottom line is that it is not possible to create an object inside a function and make it live beyond the end of that function without [explicit or implicit] dynamic memory allocation of some form. The object has to be created dynamically, end of story. There's no dynamic memory allocation in your code. Without it there's no hope of making it work. Read about dynamic memory management in C++. Alternatively, you can create local objects in the calling code and attach them to the tree (just like you do with root node). But at this time you don't do that either.

Comment: I agree with what @AnT's saying. You can't creAte objects of that class within itself as far as I know. But I might be wrong.. BTW, in the error line, since num is int, the line should be " root.value=add(root.value,num); "

Comment: @Devang Jayachandran: I'm not sure what you mean by "creAte objects of that class within itself". It is not possible to create *non-static data members* of type `T` inside class `T`, since that would constitute infinite nesting, but there's no problem in creating independent objects of type `T` inside member functions of class `T` (as the OP does). The problem in OP's code has nothing to do with "creating objects of that class within itself".

Comment: @AnT sorry man! Now I know and thanks for telling me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you are new to C++, it is not safe to return local variables or the addresses of local variables. You have to allocate space for your a `Node` in order to safely return it and in C++ that is done with `new`. Objects allocated with `new` will exist until they are deleted (**Edit**: For clarity, I mean until `delete` is used on a `Node*`)

Below I modified your code and placed comments everywhere I made a change. There were some conditions in your code where it was possible that nothing was returned (which is bad because the function is supposed to return something):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Node* left, * right;

    Node(int x, Node* l, Node* r) {
        value = x;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};

class Tree {
public:
    Node* root;

    Tree(Node *r) {
        root = r;
    }

    void add(int num) {
        cout << "adding" << endl;
        root = add(root, num);
    }

private:
    // ---------------------------------
    // Return a Node* instead of a Node
    // ---------------------------------
    //Node add(Node* parent, int num) {
    Node* add(Node* parent, int num) {

        cout << "im in..." << endl;

        if (parent == root && root == nullptr) {
            cout << "root" << endl;

            //Node n(num, nullptr, nullptr);
            //return n;

            // ------------------------------------
            // Return a new Node instead of a Node
            // ------------------------------------
            return new Node(num, nullptr, nullptr);
        }

        if (parent == nullptr) {
            //Node next(num, nullptr, nullptr);
            cout << "actually adding" << endl;
            //return next;

            // ------------------------------------
            // Return a new Node instead of a Node
            // ------------------------------------
            return new Node(num, nullptr, nullptr);
        }
        else if (num > parent->value) {
            cout << "bigger" << endl;
            parent->right = add(parent->right, num);

            // ------------------------------------
            // You are not returning anything here
            // Probably should return parent
            // ------------------------------------
            return parent;
        }
        else {
            cout << "smaller" << endl;
            parent->left = add(parent->left, num);

            // ------------------------------------
            // You are not returning anything here
            // Probably should return parent
            // ------------------------------------
            return parent;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Node n1(100, nullptr, nullptr);

    Tree tree(&n1);
    tree.add(1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
adding
im in...
smaller
im in...
actually adding
```

Comment: `Tree::add()` should not be returning `parent`, it needs to return the new `Node` that is created.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the condition above checks if `parent` is `nullptr` in which case a `new Node` is returned. If `parent` is not `nullptr` then it can be returned because it was already allocated

Comment: "its not safe to return local addresses" is an understatement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to make `Tree::add()` returns a `Node*` pointer, and have it dynamically allocate the new `Node` being added.

However, what others have not told you is that your `Tree::add()` implementation is severely broken when inserting a new `Node` next to existing `Node`(s).  You are only partially updating those existing `Nodes` to refer to the new `Node` that now resides next to them.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Node
{
public:
    int value;
    Node *left, *right;

    Node(int x, Node *l = nullptr, Node *r = nullptr)
        : value(x), left(l), right(r)
    {
    }
};

class Tree
{
public:
    Node *root;

    Tree()
        : root(nullptr)
    {
    }

    ~Tree()
    {
        Node *n = root;
        while (n != nullptr)
        {
            Node *n2 = n->right;
            delete n;
            n = n2;
        }
    }

    void add(int num)
    {
        cout << "adding" << endl;
        add(root, num);
    }

private:
    Node* add(Node *refNode, int num)
    {
        cout << "im in..." << endl;

        if (refNode == nullptr)
        {
            if (root == nullptr)
            {
                cout << "root" << endl;
                root = new Node(num);
                return root;
            }

            cout << "actually adding" << endl;
            refNode = root;
        }

        Node *newNode;

        if (num >= refNode->value)
        {
            cout << "bigger or equal" << endl;

            Node *n = refNode;
            while ((n->right != nullptr) && (num >= n->right->value))
                n = n->right;

            newNode = new Node(num, n, n->right);

            if (n->right != nullptr)
                n->right->left = newNode;
            n->right = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "smaller" << endl;

            Node *n = refNode;
            while ((n->left != nullptr) && (num < n->left->value))
                n = n->left;

            newNode = new Node(num, n->left, n);

            if (n->left != nullptr)
                n->left->right = newNode;
            n->left = newNode;

            if (n == root)
                root = newNode;
        }

        return newNode;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Tree tree;
    tree.add(100);
    tree.add(1);

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you really should use the `std::list` class instead, let it manage the nodes for you:

```
#include <list>

class Tree
{
public:
    std::list<int> nodes;

    void add(int num)
    {
        cout << "adding" << endl;

        if (nodes.empty())
        {
            cout << "root" << endl;
            nodes.push_back(num);
            return;
        }

        cout << "actually adding" << endl;

        std::list<int>::iterator iter = nodes.begin();

        if (num >= *iter)
        {
            cout << "bigger or equal" << endl;

            ++iter;
            while ((iter != nodes.end()) && (num >= *iter))
                ++iter;

            nodes.insert(iter, num);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "smaller" << endl;

            while ((iter != nodes.begin()) && (num < *(iter-1)))
                --iter;

            nodes.insert(iter, num);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Tree tree;
    tree.add(100);
    tree.add(1);

    return 0;
}
```